# Vertical multi-level accordion menu with sub-levels displayed through a <select> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, jquery-ui-accordion

I need help to modify the jQuery code of a multi-level accordion menu to be able to display level 2, level 3 and level 4 items when using a select element.

JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/841emtey/21/

1. I would like the item **Results** (level 2) to be displayed until the
   level 3 is filled. (It  appears now on the menu while no selection has been made yet) [menu 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSzIb.png).
2. When selecting **A.1** I would like to see this: [menu A.1 show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpiCn.png) :
   level 2, level 3, level 4 opened. (For now you should click on results to see the level 3 item that has been added, and when you click on this level 3 item:  *A.1 - Level 3's sub-items (level 4)* aren't not displayed because of #cssmenu ul ul {display: none;) )
3. When selecting a new item from the select element: **B.1** I would like to see this: [menu B.1 show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcs71.png) -- hide *sub-items (level 4)* of **A.1 - Level 3** and diplay the *sub-items (level 4)* of **B.1 - Level 3**.
4. Once those sub-levels added, I would like that the accordion menu works like a classic four levels menu. I mean if I click on the item **B.1 -Level 3** as it apperars on the second image, I would like its *sub-items (level 4)* be hide [menu B.1 hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAc9r.png) and then, if I click on **A.1 - Level 3**, I'd like its *sub-items (level 4)* appear [menu A.1 show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpiCn.png), etc.

```js
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('href');
  var element = $(this).parent('li');
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
   element.removeClass('open');
   element.find('li').removeClass('open');
   element.find('ul').slideUp();
  }
  else {
   element.addClass('open');
   element.children('ul').slideDown();
   element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
   element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
   element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
   element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
  }
 });

 $('#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a').append('<span class="holder"></span>');

 (function getColor() {
  var r, g, b;
  var textColor = $('#cssmenu').css('color');
  textColor = textColor.slice(4);
  r = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
  textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
  g = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
  textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
  b = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(')'));
  var l = rgbToHsl(r, g, b);
  if (l > 0.7) {
   $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
   $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
  }
  else
  {
   $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
   $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
  }
 })();

 function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
     r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
     var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
     var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

     if(max == min){
         h = s = 0;
     }
     else {
         var d = max - min;
         s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
         switch(max){
             case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
             case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
             case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
         }
         h /= 6;
     }
     return l;
 }
});
} )( jQuery );
```

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-right: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background: #36aae7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #1fa0e4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
.holder {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.holder::after,
.holder::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.holder::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a > span::after {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}
.holder::before {
  top: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-left-color: inherit;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #49505a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  background: #424852;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last.open > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 11.5px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li > a:hover::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Vertical multi-level accordion menu with sub-levels displayed through a <select> element</title> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
  
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height: 100%; } 
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function select_m(form) {
   i = form.transport_mode.selectedIndex;
   if (i == 0) {
   return;
   }
   switch (i) {
   case 1 : var txt = new Array ('A.1 - Level 3'); break;
   case 2 : var txt = new Array ('B.1 - Level 3','B.2 - Level 3','B.3 - Level 3'); break;
   }
 
  
      var select_html = '<select NAME="trasnport_line" id="trasnport_l" style="width: 200px;" onchange="Show_t_line()">' +
                        '<option selected>- Select -<\/option>';
   for (i=0;i<txt.length;i++) {
   select_html += '<option> ' + txt[i] + '<\/option>';
   }
   select_html += '<\/select>';
   document.getElementById("selection_b_l").innerHTML = select_html;  
   }
   var html2 = "";
   
 function Show_t_line() {
   html2 += '<li class="last has-sub" style="display: block"><a><span>' + document.getElementById("trasnport_l").options[document.getElementById("trasnport_l").selectedIndex].text + '</span></a><ul>';
   for (var i=0; i<1; i++) {
      html2 += '<li><a href="#"><span>' + i + '- (Level 4)</span></a></li>';
      }
      html2 += '<li class="last"><a href="#"><span>1 - (Level 4)</span></a></li></ul></li>';
   document.getElementById("side_bar_t").innerHTML = html2;
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='cssmenu' style="vertical-align: top;">
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Menu</span></a></li>
<li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products I</span></a>
         <ul>
      <form action="#">
      <li>
   <select style="width: 200px;" id="transport_m" name="transport_mode" onchange="select_m(this.form)">
      <option>- select -</option>
   <option>A</option>
         <option>B</option>
      </select>
   </li>
   <li id="selection_b_l"></li>
   </form>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Results</span></a>
   <ul id="side_bar_t" style="overflow:auto; height: 240px; display: block"></ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products II</span></a>
         <ul>
   <li class="has-sub"><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
   <ul>
   <li class="last has-sub"><a href='#'><span>Sub Product level 3</span></a>
   <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product level 4</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product level 4</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product level 3</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         </li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle instead of that amount of code.

Comment: @Farzad YZ Done, thanks.